# weaker version of fundamental theorem of calculus for non-compact intervals

Tags: calculus

Fundamental thm of calculus states:

Let $f \in C^0( [a, b], \mathbb{R})$. Let $F: [a, b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(s) ds.
$$
Then $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$. Moreover, $F \in C^1( (a, b), \mathbb{R})$.

---

Assume I have some $f$, such that for all $b \geq a$ it holds that $f \in C^0([a, b], \mathbb{R})$. Colloquially speaking, "$f$ is continuous on any compact set."

I'd like to conclude:

For all $b \geq a$ there is 
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(s) ds, 
$$
which is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$ and $F \in C^1( (a, b), \mathbb{R})$.

Hence $F \in C^0( [a, \infty), \mathbb{R})$, $F \in C^1( (a, \infty), \mathbb{R})$.

This does not look good enough to me, but I have a strong feeling this is right (can't come up with a counter-example, e.g.). Is that really allthere is, or what am I missing?

Note, that I explicitely **can't require the existence** of the improper integral 
$$
\int_a^\infty f(s) ds.
$$

Comment: This is correct and you don't require the existence of the improper integral for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FTOC really states that if $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then 
$$
F(x):=\int_a^x f(t) dt
$$
is differentiable (for $x\in (a,b)$) and that $F'(x)=f(x)$. Now if $f: [a,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, define $F: [a,\infty)$ as above. For any $b\geq a$, apply the FTOC to the interval $[a,b+1]$. Note that in particular, $b\in (a,b+1)$ so we have $F'(b)=f(b)$

Comment: Okay. Yes, the $F(x)$ as defined in your answer can then be shown to be differentiable at every point $b \geq a$. That should then be enough to have $F \in C^1( [a, \infty), \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: Well and the fact that $f=F’$ is continuous

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous on any compact set, then it is bounded. Hence,
$$
\Big |\int_a^x f(t)\,dt \Big |\leq C|x-a|,
$$
proving uniform continuity of $F$. By the fundamental theorem, since $f$ is continuous, $F'(x)=f(x)$ exists, and is obviously continuous since $f$ is.

**EDIT:** In addition to the other answers, more can be said.

1) If $\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt$ exists, then necessarily $|f(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$ such that when $x>M$, we have $|f(x)|<\epsilon$. Then the interval $[a,M]$ is compact so $f$ is bounded. In conclusion, $f$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$. As a result, for $y>x$,
$$
|F(y)-F(x)|\leq \int_x^y |f(t)|\,dt\leq C|y-x|
$$
so $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$.

2) It's possible for $\int_a^\infty f(t)\, dt$ to not exist, but because $F$ oscillates forever. For example, if $f(x)=\cos(x)$, then $F(x)=\sin(x)-\sin(a),$ which does not converge, but is bounded. By the same argument (the bounded part) as in 1), we conclude that $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$.

3) Finally, it's possible for $\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt=\pm \infty$, but $f$ is still bounded. Then uniform continuity occurs.

In conclusion, there are many scenarios where uniform continuity actually occurs. As the others pointed out, to just get the bare bones statements of the Fundamental theorem, the importance of $b$ in the theorem is negligible.

Comment: "if $f$ is continuous on any compact set, then it [I assume you mean $f$] is bounded" - I beg to differ: It's only bounded over that compeact set.
Secondly, the question is about continuity/differentiability of $F$ on an extended interval $[a, \infty]$.

Comment: See my edit. In addition to the other answers, I provide insight on what can happen at infinity.

Comment: Okay, these are very good elaborations, and give quite a lot of insight. However, there is a fourth case left, and this is the one I am actually looking for: 4) $\int_a^\infty f(t) dt = \pm \infty$ and $f$ is continuous but only bounded on compact intervals. Take, for example, $f(t) = t^2$.